Android studio - Unity build - Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: Build failed with 0 successful nodes and 1 failed ones
I have exported a Unity project and opened it with Android studio Koala. I have NDK and SDK setup. Unity can build and export the project from editor. But Android studio with the exported project can  not build apk. It is giving the following error:
Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: Build failed with 0 successful nodes and 1 failed ones

More details:
> Task :unityLibrary:BuildIl2CppTask FAILED
D:\Unity\project\Builds\PlayStore\unityLibrary\src\main\Il2CppOutputProject\IL2CPP\build\deploy\il2cpp.exe --compile-cpp --platform=Android --architecture=armv7 --outputpath=D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libil2cpp.so --baselib-directory=D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/src/main/jniStaticLibs/armeabi-v7a --incremental-g-c-time-slice=3 --enable-arm-pac-bti --configuration=Release --dotnetprofile=unityaot-linux --profiler-report --profiler-output-file=D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_armeabi-v7a_Release/il2cpp_conv.traceevents --print-command-line --data-folder=D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput/data --generatedcppdir=D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput --cachedirectory=D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_armeabi-v7a_Release/il2cpp_cache --tool-chain-path=C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.20f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK
Starting: D:\Unity\project\Builds\PlayStore\unityLibrary\src\main\Il2CppOutputProject\IL2CPP\build\deploy\bee_backend\win-x64\bee_backend.exe --verbose --threads=12 --profile="D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_armeabi-v7a_Release/il2cpp_cache/buildstate/backend_profiler0.traceevents" --beedriver-listener --dagfile="D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_armeabi-v7a_Release/il2cpp_cache/buildstate/bee.dag" --continue-on-failure FinalProgram
WorkingDir: D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_armeabi-v7a_Release/il2cpp_cache/buildstate
ExitCode: 0 Duration: 0s385ms
Build succeeded with 2 successful nodes and 0 failed ones

D:\Unity\project\Builds\PlayStore\unityLibrary\src\main\Il2CppOutputProject\IL2CPP\build\deploy\il2cpp.exe --compile-cpp --platform=Android --architecture=arm64 --outputpath=D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libil2cpp.so --baselib-directory=D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/src/main/jniStaticLibs/arm64-v8a --incremental-g-c-time-slice=3 --enable-arm-pac-bti --configuration=Release --dotnetprofile=unityaot-linux --profiler-report --profiler-output-file=D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_arm64-v8a_Release/il2cpp_conv.traceevents --print-command-line --data-folder=D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput/data --generatedcppdir=D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput --cachedirectory=D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_arm64-v8a_Release/il2cpp_cache --tool-chain-path=C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.20f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK
Starting: D:\Unity\project\Builds\PlayStore\unityLibrary\src\main\Il2CppOutputProject\IL2CPP\build\deploy\bee_backend\win-x64\bee_backend.exe --verbose --threads=12 --profile="D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_arm64-v8a_Release/il2cpp_cache/buildstate/backend_profiler0.traceevents" --beedriver-listener --dagfile="D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_arm64-v8a_Release/il2cpp_cache/buildstate/bee.dag" --continue-on-failure FinalProgram
WorkingDir: D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_arm64-v8a_Release/il2cpp_cache/buildstate
ExitCode: 3 Duration: 0s241ms
Build failed with 0 successful nodes and 1 failed ones
Annotation: Link_Android_arm64 d8kz/libil2cpp.so
Cmdline: "C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.20f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++" @"D:\Unity\project\Builds\PlayStore\unityLibrary\build\il2cpp_arm64-v8a_Release\il2cpp_cache\buildstate\artifacts\rsp\1729919944154292146.rsp"
ExitCode: 1
rsp: -march=armv8-a -mbranch-protection=standard -D__ANDROID_UNAVAILABLE_SYMBOLS_ARE_WEAK__ -faddrsig -DANDROID -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H -no-canonical-prefixes -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fomit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -Wswitch -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-implicitly-unsigned-literal -Wno-integer-overflow -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-unknown-attributes -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-null-conversion -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-unused-value -Wno-pragma-once-outside-header -fvisibility=hidden -fexceptions -fno-rtti -g -Os -fPIC -fno-strict-overflow -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -o "d8kz/libil2cpp.so" -fcolor-diagnostics -fdiagnostics-absolute-paths -target aarch64-linux-android22 -fstrict-aliasing -fdiagnostics-format=msvc "d8kz/x30lh88e3tsj.o" "d8kz/6ia7iflrojqf.o" "d8kz/rydvyozor71y.o" "d8kz/s6xbj4fnv9ie.o" "d8kz/mpjya7lnfmg1.o" "d8kz/9mjyb0h7samd.o" "d8kz/u2mmr9v4vyxw.o" "d8kz/fiqa7ia2ym9f.o" "d8kz/r0j86mq6ng4j.o" "d8kz/ghk69s3x8cc5.o" "d8kz/1wnup2hvb1no.o" "d8kz/247aaiytf343.o" "d8kz/nkbzprcrirgn.o" "d8kz/8zen50qolfs6.o" "d8kz/97y3pg7mph9l.o" "d8kz/un2r5plks5k5.o" "d8kz/f35flzzhvtwo.o" "d8kz/h5ga0da4vymm.o" "d8kz/j4len0t17lwk.o" "d8kz/z1y62w25mn0m.o" "d8kz/8y3f1515ko8c.o" "d8kz/f4o0bik8p46z.o" "d8kz/i7ahve27jxye.o" "d8kz/04y22vv6v48h.o" "d8kz/b09py8dtfk0y.o" "d8kz/wfdeeisqi8bi.o" "d8kz/el0fm1y4imi8.o" "d8kz/9k31zd2ram3r.o" "d8kz/lknpoue65zxw.o" "d8kz/9g8wgkf8xlqd.o" "d8kz/hm44mopm4zuk.o" "d8kz/q4lfla8qtqss.o" "d8kz/j1c9pzy2awmu.o" "d8kz/k0u74yb5nxsm.o" "d8kz/f5vveho6wwqg.o" "d8kz/68abo1614h7v.o" "d8kz/dybkh4klibn8.o" "d8kz/4j6l7okduxlf.o" "d8kz/j2s650soc434.o" "d8kz/zwnuzcrmqj60.o" "d8kz/kcrifm5jt7hk.o" "d8kz/5ru6uvjhwvt3.o" "d8kz/6zenfb0f0xaj.o" "d8kz/rfibvked3lm2.o" "d8kz/cvlzausa69xl.o" "d8kz/d35fv9889bf1.o" "d8kz/yi93ajn6c0qk.o" "d8kz/zqtkvy34g27z.o" "d8kz/k6w8a8h2jqjj.o" "d8kz/kadnqg9mg6kk.o" "d8kz/6ynd8zg3so5v.o" "d8kz/rer1n9u0vchf.o" "d8kz/smbi8obzzeyu.o" "d8kz/d2e6nypw229d.o" "d8kz/5pgb6pnkjuw3.o" "d8kz/q5jzlz1hmi8m.o" "d8kz/rd4f6eigqkp2.o" "d8kz/ct73lowdt80l.o" "d8kz/d1rk63ccxai1.o" "d8kz/ygv8ldr9zytk.o" "d8kz/jwyw1m562m53.o" "d8kz/8js4zij5y5sm.o" "d8kz/vii5wmt1dcip.o" "d8kz/gyltcw7yg0t8.o" "d8kz/h659wboxk2ao.o" "d8kz/2l9xcl2unqm7.o" "d8kz/n1cmsugsqeyq.o" "d8kz/o9w2caxqugf6.o" "d8kz/9o0qsjbox4qp.o" "d8kz/axk7czrm1674.o" "d8kz/ixcl1932psvx.o" "d8kz/h72nalfimcku.o" "d8kz/2b0ow6y2zl8x.o" "d8kz/nr3ccgd029jh.o" "d8kz/8660rprx5xv0.o" "d8kz/9erhc57v9zcg.o" "d8kz/eckbqerkftuh.o" "d8kz/szn14t71fz8m.o" "d8kz/fil0juon52sb.o" "d8kz/gq5g494l949q.o" "d8kz/1584jjjjctla.o" "d8kz/mlctzsxgfhxt.o" "d8kz/ntw9j8dfjje9.o" "d8kz/88zxzhscm7ps.o" "d8kz/to3lfr69ov1b.o" "d8kz/uwn2z6m8sxir.o" "d8kz/fcrqfg15vlua.o" "d8kz/kowou07oue4x.o" "d8kz/2lgceg1wg5cm.o" "d8kz/3kqun339ukgs.o" "d8kz/xdtyzszuhc0x.o" "d8kz/0xfaggrzndmv.o" "d8kz/y1a3o5bt3ned.o" "d8kz/jher4eqq6bqw.o" "d8kz/4whfko4n9z1f.o" "d8kz/541v43kmd2iv.o" "d8kz/qk5jkdzjgque.o" "d8kz/rsp04sfiksbu.o" "d8kz/c8sok2tfngnd.o" "d8kz/ldjyvp5wq1xe.o" "d8kz/6smmbzjutp9x.o" "d8kz/7062ve0sxrqd.o" "d8kz/sgarboeq0f2w.o" "d8kz/dwdfrxsn33dg.o" "d8kz/e4xvbd9l75uv.o" "d8kz/zj1jrmnjau6e.o" "d8kz/0rl0b23hewnu.o" "d8kz/xow5m246nwjn.o" "d8kz/p9bs1g4vvaz4.o" "d8kz/apfghqityyao.o" "d8kz/i4zt2bj4qkv6.o" "d8kz/3j3hilx1t86p.o" "d8kz/4rny20d0xao5.o" "d8kz/p7qmiasx0yzo.o" "d8kz/qfb32p8v40g4.o" "d8kz/bverizmt7osn.o" "d8kz/waify80qad46.o" "d8kz/xi2viohpeflm.o" "d8kz/erilq9pzb74d.o" "d8kz/9buf56hszqwp.o" "d8kz/1a6vstjrc42p.o" "d8kz/i0y0vya4cy2y.o" "d8kz/2o7b5lpi2z4k.o" "d8kz/wrfakziwrfbk.o" "d8kz/p8kiwgto7q3d.o" "d8kz/aoo6bq7laffx.o" "d8kz/3l0e15w7ej3f.o" "d8kz/f4wctaaor1jb.o" "d8kz/gxkzzfcxk4bb.o" "d8kz/h54fkvsvo6sq.o" "d8kz/thtqu22l96go.o" "d8kz/xknf6soh3383.o" "d8kz/ah6tup74b5pj.o" "d8kz/vw9hazl2et12.o" "d8kz/o5g9im6y745c.o" "d8kz/fx5y6hkxkmc8.o" "d8kz/3phtjd8rrlwa.o" "d8kz/4x193soqvndq.o" "d8kz/0c9mmryunaor.o" "d8kz/1kt366etrc56.o" "d8kz/m0wrmgtqu0gq.o" "d8kz/n8g86v9oy2x5.o" "d8kz/8nkwm5nm1q9o.o" "d8kz/t3nk2e2j4el8.o" "d8kz/ub80muii8g2n.o" "d8kz/frbp23wfb5d7.o" "d8kz/xxd9wew3aavd.o" "d8kz/9rvy1on1yqql.o" "d8kz/yh0zusnaqg8b.o" "d8kz/jx3na217s4jv.o" "d8kz/k5n4uhi6w60a.o" "d8kz/5krsarw3zucu.o" "d8kz/q0ugq0a12iod.o" "d8kz/r8exagrz6k5s.o" "d8kz/crchldf4na44.o" "d8kz/gqe0gxvjlkpm.o" "d8kz/q74sy3t4bnwq.o" "d8kz/y2htqr9moh9w.o" "d8kz/t18c0304405h.o" "d8kz/6h5xdn9kus8w.o" "d8kz/7ppey2pjyupc.o" "d8kz/ajvc083q6ulo.o" "d8kz/o4lkkhckux8y.o" "d8kz/53i3ujkqsqh0.o" "d8kz/zaaezbta44yv.o" "d8kz/of3dr8mldqum.o" "d8kz/7nnr33fiipfy.o" "d8kz/cgvye4cmb92t.o" "d8kz/rrl8lqzrldbm.o" "d8kz/51tcgxrj36ns.o" "d8kz/b068yhrhmt6z.o" "d8kz/5790mm7s9f1g.o" "d8kz/hdb5s5q0l7m4.o" "d8kz/8xe877n2cus4.o" "d8kz/bxug89o8uwxr.o" "d8kz/1uhxhssei3av.o" "d8kz/2netwtjupbyq.o" "d8kz/3vy9g9zstdf6.o" "d8kz/ob2xwieqw1qp.o" "d8kz/nz1v4tq8rquu.o" "d8kz/6ioywz1sxngx.o" "d8kz/6gcklx3hz9ez.o" "d8kz/xvh3s97117h4.o" "d8kz/icel57p1i20h.o" "d8kz/csjlbjjvb6a2.o" "d8kz/x7m9qsxseuml.o" "d8kz/yf7pb8driw30.o" "d8kz/jvaerhsolkfk.o" "d8kz/k3uubx8mpmwz.o" "d8kz/jky1pn6zm4hx.o" "d8kz/4z1p5wkxpstg.o" "d8kz/57l6pc1vtuaw.o" "d8kz/qnpu5lftwimf.o" "d8kz/b3silvtqz6xy.o" "d8kz/cbdz5aap38ee.o" "d8kz/xqgnlkom6wqx.o" "d8kz/i6jb1t2j9k2g.o" "d8kz/u2lq9gla0b55.o" "d8kz/disb1y7u1mbc.o" "d8kz/yxvzg8ls4anv.o" "d8kz/z5fg1n2q8c4a.o" "d8kz/wd9b2joq742b.o" "d8kz/kwfa257p6049.o" "d8kz/uwr4zb64nlsg.o" "d8kz/d1kyqv20cu23.o" "d8kz/x2ssde7vphwx.o" "d8kz/fyplvgj8ow2n.o" "d8kz/bory010z2ork.o" "d8kz/3zkm7lypwmms.o" "d8kz/yc3crkyoglyd.o" "d8kz/o8q7wubm763h.o" "d8kz/wpvyiadhkczk.o" "d8kz/4o0c05s5okp4.o" "d8kz/mke3yut2k5ig.o" "d8kz/3xhgwx52qjwa.o" "d8kz/gx34elf0c086.o" "d8kz/tvyqjlficzgv.o" "d8kz/rcc5exnh335b.o" "d8kz/p5eow8aitef8.o" "d8kz/7temvt9u931r.o" "d8kz/pekbsbo0skt7.o" "d8kz/ah9layevcsbx.o" "d8kz/09wrgmexab1u.o" "d8kz/s0n4bi35i4qv.o" "d8kz/6s2mogeg9rga.o" "d8kz/95jwvi1cue7q.o" "d8kz/kub3iqk5vl0i.o" "d8kz/cnvzqg9rhi1g.o" "d8kz/a1qsv3mffed8.o" "d8kz/dvwz3mc64pj8.o" "d8kz/jm1hryxr9bqm.o" "d8kz/edmnkhru7zpi.o" "d8kz/qdt5tk4rdcka.o" "d8kz/5xfodupv6ttv.o" "d8kz/tx17at4bgdxa.o" "d8kz/g8y6kl74t0ga.o" "d8kz/u3yylhyxmm38.o" "d8kz/z02fo3844v6r.o" "d8kz/rpipjxh1m4xg.o" "d8kz/5fj7v8p8kuwd.o" "d8kz/1s34ezrcdgr9.o" "d8kz/oq6lxul63efg.o" "d8kz/tvwp3qos2udl.o" "d8kz/p18ngglznf69.o" "d8kz/skzrg8xmxy7p.o" "d8kz/kiw89b1gk8p6.o" "d8kz/yudjfhlplkyw.o" "d8kz/yzwes16f8h9a.o" "d8kz/h1b6439mft1t.o" "d8kz/0m5p5i374hw6.o" "d8kz/5sdikgqbh5zf.o" "d8kz/v06k29scyg63.o" "d8kz/ja88b3ydhnbf.o" "d8kz/8dgtstai2roy.o" "d8kz/r4is5utuadzg.o" "d8kz/952n41302okn.o" "d8kz/voyt2dg66zii.o" "d8kz/dvgqdg7ybdvh.o" "d8kz/l9d2ekvjpgdw.o" "d8kz/k0tjljfxicys.o" "d8kz/z8esgeuz1r71.o" "d8kz/tl0t63544gcm.o" "d8kz/fuj7y6wzg4vk.o" "d8kz/ipahvr1xkbat.o" "d8kz/pip895bwfcr4.o" "d8kz/qkymlwy7cro5.o" "d8kz/6d71qdaapl1t.o" "d8kz/g2imwx2dkxeo.o" "d8kz/wy21q1jcg7p1.o" "d8kz/2xep5o5l9za5.o" "d8kz/iomndamcxpfj.o" "87li/050fp5uqmzh6.o" "87li/06clmos0284o.o" "87li/0eralkd5bsuj.o" "87li/0hgv936drm7a.o" "87li/0inqe5kxq5x8.o" "87li/0x7olacj5a4g.o" "87li/1lorcnkwbkl0.o" "87li/1tnluwjysowj.o" "87li/1v1ozhgp3de8.o" "87li/1v41emxdzohh.o" "87li/21fgqqyl7les.o" "87li/2gtnuhnwra2i.o" "87li/3cvtyve30ojh.o" "87li/3j4bubs264yh.o" "87li/3w0iq6qfqr22.o" "87li/4049hj7jfxfq.o" "87li/44y9dvi07z1u.o" "87li/51m4rm6oq6yw.o" "87li/533bqin14p1i.o" "87li/5f66z79pakku.o" "87li/5n7go7zj76hm.o" "87li/72na2hc5xdhk.o" "87li/72xymw8gwsx3.o" "87li/7jue1vk0bp5p.o" "87li/7k5nq38kvat1.o" "87li/7zjkym90nr0l.o" "87li/8709u1zo3vxo.o" "87li/8cug3chhb9aq.o" "87li/8e5hiczwwczj.o" "87li/8k3pv91r7ybn.o" "87li/9eur572tg0bi.o" "87li/9kld5ezucjza.o" "87li/9yh83j2wdji7.o" "87li/amys3pa9ttxe.o" "87li/b1qzbk906jaq.o" "87li/buljy33sztaq.o" "87li/cne7892w7umv.o" "87li/d6folvw8noe1.o" "87li/d7o1lxd9k65i.o" "87li/dbh37iiisnge.o" "87li/dvqq7aqx8gzq.o" "87li/ecbse2tr9y23.o" "87li/ejca5xreknzk.o" "87li/enc20unijzpf.o" "87li/f16o0jybpaaw.o" "87li/g3z0q4plnkw9.o" "87li/g479msn9kgqg.o" "87li/g6vdzd4g9hqd.o" "87li/gvkg9pzfomvr.o" "87li/hbe7v3amoq2e.o" "87li/hvlagasv5ejy.o" "87li/i2xlcnnd36cs.o" "87li/iaxg68jreqz9.o" "87li/ikh71rwflqqq.o" "87li/irl6rvlyr21i.o" "87li/jhsqvjvvjt3w.o" "87li/k7vcl0xiwi37.o" "87li/kciu10i3wgf0.o" "87li/kp3v7193fkqb.o" "87li/ku1z8effkj9m.o" "87li/kutzac719iy6.o" "87li/m028wrtzf9jr.o" "87li/m8oe4vn8ovoa.o" "87li/mpf8wx72h705.o" "87li/mva3v9zsfsw5.o" "87li/mvdq88bpnrbw.o" "87li/n0arkrn5go9k.o" "87li/n8de9977b065.o" "87li/ngzxktc9wpe5.o" "87li/nixdn7hb6gvu.o" "87li/nq24jzm179jq.o" "87li/nq6um8vmsyj2.o" "87li/nsxb2l919072.o" "87li/os7jyte7c7f2.o" "87li/ot21nv0qaipi.o" "87li/otxgwebcenhb.o" "87li/ow2um3sf7ryz.o" "87li/ow56jmgck9ca.o" "87li/p6o63xasda84.o" "87li/pbymc18rhyov.o" "87li/pjdryzr3bp0l.o" "87li/qjl9lzl9c4pf.o" "87li/qnudrp1yzkrg.o" "87li/r3801maus68b.o" "87li/ravg4ql6ojfk.o" "87li/rjak05dskqlj.o" "87li/rjsk1f0t0pjf.o" "87li/s76wfa8grgha.o" "87li/sa9iay21ad4x.o" "87li/spzo558v9poz.o" "87li/ssnivl3wuh0q.o" "87li/t64vsxz2v07a.o" "87li/tcgk1845h1dz.o" "87li/u2222nyxw5z9.o" "87li/vgjygbly1k88.o" "87li/vpphcw25iwmh.o" "87li/vtj1b6056sks.o" "87li/vzjmyl1xnfk5.o" "87li/wpfeu5x6rgo5.o" "87li/wvq22g39dhut.o" "87li/ww4cc5satchf.o" "87li/xgddb2b2io5l.o" "87li/xldl4vw1slg4.o" "87li/xp2xpuljxi52.o" "87li/xyf2wq0pl7ti.o" "87li/ycujdez9280m.o" "87li/yghjjh0te7c4.o" "87li/yqc170h5s20j.o" "87li/yvkj6018hkr2.o" "87li/z96fh9flmvb1.o" "87li/ze1k4o1daxao.o" "87li/zjq5sf0jxwvj.o" "87li/zxkuyiy6p7xl.o" "87li/zzqwu5lthkc4.o" "dqdh/31mb4eijn0rc.o" "dqdh/41ki1812f4ak.o" "zz99/2x31ycfew74i.o" "zz99/3duw0f1mq17l.o" "zz99/50auwti6eb52.o" "zz99/5ygv0jltyau5.o" "zz99/8q1k1ot9r7wg.o" "zz99/af8mibrlgk08.o" "zz99/c3qjycqghyjx.o" "zz99/js7sk1zknd9m.o" "zz99/nv7lyet7ipb0.o" "zz99/p730vz8clvm1.o" "zz99/sds4qz2mpzk9.o" "zz99/tnzifh17zrty.o" "zz99/uzcny9iwvomn.o" "zz99/zk3v4t7u36is.o" -Wl,--wrap,sigaction -fuse-ld=lld.exe -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,-soname=libil2cpp.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -static-libstdc++  -Wl,--icf=safe "D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/src/main/jniStaticLibs/arm64-v8a/baselib.a" -l"log"
Stdout: 
clang++: error: no such file or directory: 'D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/src/main/jniStaticLibs/arm64-v8a/baselib.a'

Error: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: Build failed with 0 successful nodes and 1 failed ones
Annotation: Link_Android_arm64 d8kz/libil2cpp.so
Cmdline: "C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.20f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++" @"D:\Unity\project\Builds\PlayStore\unityLibrary\build\il2cpp_arm64-v8a_Release\il2cpp_cache\buildstate\artifacts\rsp\1729919944154292146.rsp"
Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: Build failed with 0 successful nodes and 1 failed ones

ExitCode: 1
rsp: -march=armv8-a -mbranch-protection=standard -D__ANDROID_UNAVAILABLE_SYMBOLS_ARE_WEAK__ -faddrsig -DANDROID -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H -no-canonical-prefixes -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fomit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -Wswitch -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-implicitly-unsigned-literal -Wno-integer-overflow -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-unknown-attributes -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-null-conversion -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-unused-value -Wno-pragma-once-outside-header -fvisibility=hidden -fexceptions -fno-rtti -g -Os -fPIC -fno-strict-overflow -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -o "d8kz/libil2cpp.so" -fcolor-diagnostics -fdiagnostics-absolute-paths -target aarch64-linux-android22 -fstrict-aliasing -fdiagnostics-format=msvc "d8kz/x30lh88e3tsj.o" "d8kz/6ia7iflrojqf.o" "d8kz/rydvyozor71y.o" "d8kz/s6xbj4fnv9ie.o" "d8kz/mpjya7lnfmg1.o" "d8kz/9mjyb0h7samd.o" "d8kz/u2mmr9v4vyxw.o" "d8kz/fiqa7ia2ym9f.o" "d8kz/r0j86mq6ng4j.o" "d8kz/ghk69s3x8cc5.o" "d8kz/1wnup2hvb1no.o" "d8kz/247aaiytf343.o" "d8kz/nkbzprcrirgn.o" "d8kz/8zen50qolfs6.o" "d8kz/97y3pg7mph9l.o" "d8kz/un2r5plks5k5.o" "d8kz/f35flzzhvtwo.o" "d8kz/h5ga0da4vymm.o" "d8kz/j4len0t17lwk.o" "d8kz/z1y62w25mn0m.o" "d8kz/8y3f1515ko8c.o" "d8kz/f4o0bik8p46z.o" "d8kz/i7ahve27jxye.o" "d8kz/04y22vv6v48h.o" "d8kz/b09py8dtfk0y.o" "d8kz/wfdeeisqi8bi.o" "d8kz/el0fm1y4imi8.o" "d8kz/9k31zd2ram3r.o" "d8kz/lknpoue65zxw.o" "d8kz/9g8wgkf8xlqd.o" "d8kz/hm44mopm4zuk.o" "d8kz/q4lfla8qtqss.o" "d8kz/j1c9pzy2awmu.o" "d8kz/k0u74yb5nxsm.o" "d8kz/f5vveho6wwqg.o" "d8kz/68abo1614h7v.o" "d8kz/dybkh4klibn8.o" "d8kz/4j6l7okduxlf.o" "d8kz/j2s650soc434.o" "d8kz/zwnuzcrmqj60.o" "d8kz/kcrifm5jt7hk.o" "d8kz/5ru6uvjhwvt3.o" "d8kz/6zenfb0f0xaj.o" "d8kz/rfibvked3lm2.o" "d8kz/cvlzausa69xl.o" "d8kz/d35fv9889bf1.o" "d8kz/yi93ajn6c0qk.o" "d8kz/zqtkvy34g27z.o" "d8kz/k6w8a8h2jqjj.o" "d8kz/kadnqg9mg6kk.o" "d8kz/6ynd8zg3so5v.o" "d8kz/rer1n9u0vchf.o" "d8kz/smbi8obzzeyu.o" "d8kz/d2e6nypw229d.o" "d8kz/5pgb6pnkjuw3.o" "d8kz/q5jzlz1hmi8m.o" "d8kz/rd4f6eigqkp2.o" "d8kz/ct73lowdt80l.o" "d8kz/d1rk63ccxai1.o" "d8kz/ygv8ldr9zytk.o" "d8kz/jwyw1m562m53.o" "d8kz/8js4zij5y5sm.o" "d8kz/vii5wmt1dcip.o" "d8kz/gyltcw7yg0t8.o" "d8kz/h659wboxk2ao.o" "d8kz/2l9xcl2unqm7.o" "d8kz/n1cmsugsqeyq.o" "d8kz/o9w2caxqugf6.o" "d8kz/9o0qsjbox4qp.o" "d8kz/axk7czrm1674.o" "d8kz/ixcl1932psvx.o" "d8kz/h72nalfimcku.o" "d8kz/2b0ow6y2zl8x.o" "d8kz/nr3ccgd029jh.o" "d8kz/8660rprx5xv0.o" "d8kz/9erhc57v9zcg.o" "d8kz/eckbqerkftuh.o" "d8kz/szn14t71fz8m.o" "d8kz/fil0juon52sb.o" "d8kz/gq5g494l949q.o" "d8kz/1584jjjjctla.o" "d8kz/mlctzsxgfhxt.o" "d8kz/ntw9j8dfjje9.o" "d8kz/88zxzhscm7ps.o" "d8kz/to3lfr69ov1b.o" "d8kz/uwn2z6m8sxir.o" "d8kz/fcrqfg15vlua.o" "d8kz/kowou07oue4x.o" "d8kz/2lgceg1wg5cm.o" "d8kz/3kqun339ukgs.o" "d8kz/xdtyzszuhc0x.o" "d8kz/0xfaggrzndmv.o" "d8kz/y1a3o5bt3ned.o" "d8kz/jher4eqq6bqw.o" "d8kz/4whfko4n9z1f.o" "d8kz/541v43kmd2iv.o" "d8kz/qk5jkdzjgque.o" "d8kz/rsp04sfiksbu.o" "d8kz/c8sok2tfngnd.o" "d8kz/ldjyvp5wq1xe.o" "d8kz/6smmbzjutp9x.o" "d8kz/7062ve0sxrqd.o" "d8kz/sgarboeq0f2w.o" "d8kz/dwdfrxsn33dg.o" "d8kz/e4xvbd9l75uv.o" "d8kz/zj1jrmnjau6e.o" "d8kz/0rl0b23hewnu.o" "d8kz/xow5m246nwjn.o" "d8kz/p9bs1g4vvaz4.o" "d8kz/apfghqityyao.o" "d8kz/i4zt2bj4qkv6.o" "d8kz/3j3hilx1t86p.o" "d8kz/4rny20d0xao5.o" "d8kz/p7qmiasx0yzo.o" "d8kz/qfb32p8v40g4.o" "d8kz/bverizmt7osn.o" "d8kz/waify80qad46.o" "d8kz/xi2viohpeflm.o" "d8kz/erilq9pzb74d.o" "d8kz/9buf56hszqwp.o" "d8kz/1a6vstjrc42p.o" "d8kz/i0y0vya4cy2y.o" "d8kz/2o7b5lpi2z4k.o" "d8kz/wrfakziwrfbk.o" "d8kz/p8kiwgto7q3d.o" "d8kz/aoo6bq7laffx.o" "d8kz/3l0e15w7ej3f.o" "d8kz/f4wctaaor1jb.o" "d8kz/gxkzzfcxk4bb.o" "d8kz/h54fkvsvo6sq.o" "d8kz/thtqu22l96go.o" "d8kz/xknf6soh3383.o" "d8kz/ah6tup74b5pj.o" "d8kz/vw9hazl2et12.o" "d8kz/o5g9im6y745c.o" "d8kz/fx5y6hkxkmc8.o" "d8kz/3phtjd8rrlwa.o" "d8kz/4x193soqvndq.o" "d8kz/0c9mmryunaor.o" "d8kz/1kt366etrc56.o" "d8kz/m0wrmgtqu0gq.o" "d8kz/n8g86v9oy2x5.o" "d8kz/8nkwm5nm1q9o.o" "d8kz/t3nk2e2j4el8.o" "d8kz/ub80muii8g2n.o" "d8kz/frbp23wfb5d7.o" "d8kz/xxd9wew3aavd.o" "d8kz/9rvy1on1yqql.o" "d8kz/yh0zusnaqg8b.o" "d8kz/jx3na217s4jv.o" "d8kz/k5n4uhi6w60a.o" "d8kz/5krsarw3zucu.o" "d8kz/q0ugq0a12iod.o" "d8kz/r8exagrz6k5s.o" "d8kz/crchldf4na44.o" "d8kz/gqe0gxvjlkpm.o" "d8kz/q74sy3t4bnwq.o" "d8kz/y2htqr9moh9w.o" "d8kz/t18c0304405h.o" "d8kz/6h5xdn9kus8w.o" "d8kz/7ppey2pjyupc.o" "d8kz/ajvc083q6ulo.o" "d8kz/o4lkkhckux8y.o" "d8kz/53i3ujkqsqh0.o" "d8kz/zaaezbta44yv.o" "d8kz/of3dr8mldqum.o" "d8kz/7nnr33fiipfy.o" "d8kz/cgvye4cmb92t.o" "d8kz/rrl8lqzrldbm.o" "d8kz/51tcgxrj36ns.o" "d8kz/b068yhrhmt6z.o" "d8kz/5790mm7s9f1g.o" "d8kz/hdb5s5q0l7m4.o" "d8kz/8xe877n2cus4.o" "d8kz/bxug89o8uwxr.o" "d8kz/1uhxhssei3av.o" "d8kz/2netwtjupbyq.o" "d8kz/3vy9g9zstdf6.o" "d8kz/ob2xwieqw1qp.o" "d8kz/nz1v4tq8rquu.o" "d8kz/6ioywz1sxngx.o" "d8kz/6gcklx3hz9ez.o" "d8kz/xvh3s97117h4.o" "d8kz/icel57p1i20h.o" "d8kz/csjlbjjvb6a2.o" "d8kz/x7m9qsxseuml.o" "d8kz/yf7pb8driw30.o" "d8kz/jvaerhsolkfk.o" "d8kz/k3uubx8mpmwz.o" "d8kz/jky1pn6zm4hx.o" "d8kz/4z1p5wkxpstg.o" "d8kz/57l6pc1vtuaw.o" "d8kz/qnpu5lftwimf.o" "d8kz/b3silvtqz6xy.o" "d8kz/cbdz5aap38ee.o" "d8kz/xqgnlkom6wqx.o" "d8kz/i6jb1t2j9k2g.o" "d8kz/u2lq9gla0b55.o" "d8kz/disb1y7u1mbc.o" "d8kz/yxvzg8ls4anv.o" "d8kz/z5fg1n2q8c4a.o" "d8kz/wd9b2joq742b.o" "d8kz/kwfa257p6049.o" "d8kz/uwr4zb64nlsg.o" "d8kz/d1kyqv20cu23.o" "d8kz/x2ssde7vphwx.o" "d8kz/fyplvgj8ow2n.o" "d8kz/bory010z2ork.o" "d8kz/3zkm7lypwmms.o" "d8kz/yc3crkyoglyd.o" "d8kz/o8q7wubm763h.o" "d8kz/wpvyiadhkczk.o" "d8kz/4o0c05s5okp4.o" "d8kz/mke3yut2k5ig.o" "d8kz/3xhgwx52qjwa.o" "d8kz/gx34elf0c086.o" "d8kz/tvyqjlficzgv.o" "d8kz/rcc5exnh335b.o" "d8kz/p5eow8aitef8.o" "d8kz/7temvt9u931r.o" "d8kz/pekbsbo0skt7.o" "d8kz/ah9layevcsbx.o" "d8kz/09wrgmexab1u.o" "d8kz/s0n4bi35i4qv.o" "d8kz/6s2mogeg9rga.o" "d8kz/95jwvi1cue7q.o" "d8kz/kub3iqk5vl0i.o" "d8kz/cnvzqg9rhi1g.o" "d8kz/a1qsv3mffed8.o" "d8kz/dvwz3mc64pj8.o" "d8kz/jm1hryxr9bqm.o" "d8kz/edmnkhru7zpi.o" "d8kz/qdt5tk4rdcka.o" "d8kz/5xfodupv6ttv.o" "d8kz/tx17at4bgdxa.o" "d8kz/g8y6kl74t0ga.o" "d8kz/u3yylhyxmm38.o" "d8kz/z02fo3844v6r.o" "d8kz/rpipjxh1m4xg.o" "d8kz/5fj7v8p8kuwd.o" "d8kz/1s34ezrcdgr9.o" "d8kz/oq6lxul63efg.o" "d8kz/tvwp3qos2udl.o" "d8kz/p18ngglznf69.o" "d8kz/skzrg8xmxy7p.o" "d8kz/kiw89b1gk8p6.o" "d8kz/yudjfhlplkyw.o" "d8kz/yzwes16f8h9a.o" "d8kz/h1b6439mft1t.o" "d8kz/0m5p5i374hw6.o" "d8kz/5sdikgqbh5zf.o" "d8kz/v06k29scyg63.o" "d8kz/ja88b3ydhnbf.o" "d8kz/8dgtstai2roy.o" "d8kz/r4is5utuadzg.o" "d8kz/952n41302okn.o" "d8kz/voyt2dg66zii.o" "d8kz/dvgqdg7ybdvh.o" "d8kz/l9d2ekvjpgdw.o" "d8kz/k0tjljfxicys.o" "d8kz/z8esgeuz1r71.o" "d8kz/tl0t63544gcm.o" "d8kz/fuj7y6wzg4vk.o" "d8kz/ipahvr1xkbat.o" "d8kz/pip895bwfcr4.o" "d8kz/qkymlwy7cro5.o" "d8kz/6d71qdaapl1t.o" "d8kz/g2imwx2dkxeo.o" "d8kz/wy21q1jcg7p1.o" "d8kz/2xep5o5l9za5.o" "d8kz/iomndamcxpfj.o" "87li/050fp5uqmzh6.o" "87li/06clmos0284o.o" "87li/0eralkd5bsuj.o" "87li/0hgv936drm7a.o" "87li/0inqe5kxq5x8.o" "87li/0x7olacj5a4g.o" "87li/1lorcnkwbkl0.o" "87li/1tnluwjysowj.o" "87li/1v1ozhgp3de8.o" "87li/1v41emxdzohh.o" "87li/21fgqqyl7les.o" "87li/2gtnuhnwra2i.o" "87li/3cvtyve30ojh.o" "87li/3j4bubs264yh.o" "87li/3w0iq6qfqr22.o" "87li/4049hj7jfxfq.o" "87li/44y9dvi07z1u.o" "87li/51m4rm6oq6yw.o" "87li/533bqin14p1i.o" "87li/5f66z79pakku.o" "87li/5n7go7zj76hm.o" "87li/72na2hc5xdhk.o" "87li/72xymw8gwsx3.o" "87li/7jue1vk0bp5p.o" "87li/7k5nq38kvat1.o" "87li/7zjkym90nr0l.o" "87li/8709u1zo3vxo.o" "87li/8cug3chhb9aq.o" "87li/8e5hiczwwczj.o" "87li/8k3pv91r7ybn.o" "87li/9eur572tg0bi.o" "87li/9kld5ezucjza.o" "87li/9yh83j2wdji7.o" "87li/amys3pa9ttxe.o" "87li/b1qzbk906jaq.o" "87li/buljy33sztaq.o" "87li/cne7892w7umv.o" "87li/d6folvw8noe1.o" "87li/d7o1lxd9k65i.o" "87li/dbh37iiisnge.o" "87li/dvqq7aqx8gzq.o" "87li/ecbse2tr9y23.o" "87li/ejca5xreknzk.o" "87li/enc20unijzpf.o" "87li/f16o0jybpaaw.o" "87li/g3z0q4plnkw9.o" "87li/g479msn9kgqg.o" "87li/g6vdzd4g9hqd.o" "87li/gvkg9pzfomvr.o" "87li/hbe7v3amoq2e.o" "87li/hvlagasv5ejy.o" "87li/i2xlcnnd36cs.o" "87li/iaxg68jreqz9.o" "87li/ikh71rwflqqq.o" "87li/irl6rvlyr21i.o" "87li/jhsqvjvvjt3w.o" "87li/k7vcl0xiwi37.o" "87li/kciu10i3wgf0.o" "87li/kp3v7193fkqb.o" "87li/ku1z8effkj9m.o" "87li/kutzac719iy6.o" "87li/m028wrtzf9jr.o" "87li/m8oe4vn8ovoa.o" "87li/mpf8wx72h705.o" "87li/mva3v9zsfsw5.o" "87li/mvdq88bpnrbw.o" "87li/n0arkrn5go9k.o" "87li/n8de9977b065.o" "87li/ngzxktc9wpe5.o" "87li/nixdn7hb6gvu.o" "87li/nq24jzm179jq.o" "87li/nq6um8vmsyj2.o" "87li/nsxb2l919072.o" "87li/os7jyte7c7f2.o" "87li/ot21nv0qaipi.o" "87li/otxgwebcenhb.o" "87li/ow2um3sf7ryz.o" "87li/ow56jmgck9ca.o" "87li/p6o63xasda84.o" "87li/pbymc18rhyov.o" "87li/pjdryzr3bp0l.o" "87li/qjl9lzl9c4pf.o" "87li/qnudrp1yzkrg.o" "87li/r3801maus68b.o" "87li/ravg4ql6ojfk.o" "87li/rjak05dskqlj.o" "87li/rjsk1f0t0pjf.o" "87li/s76wfa8grgha.o" "87li/sa9iay21ad4x.o" "87li/spzo558v9poz.o" "87li/ssnivl3wuh0q.o" "87li/t64vsxz2v07a.o" "87li/tcgk1845h1dz.o" "87li/u2222nyxw5z9.o" "87li/vgjygbly1k88.o" "87li/vpphcw25iwmh.o" "87li/vtj1b6056sks.o" "87li/vzjmyl1xnfk5.o" "87li/wpfeu5x6rgo5.o" "87li/wvq22g39dhut.o" "87li/ww4cc5satchf.o" "87li/xgddb2b2io5l.o" "87li/xldl4vw1slg4.o" "87li/xp2xpuljxi52.o" "87li/xyf2wq0pl7ti.o" "87li/ycujdez9280m.o" "87li/yghjjh0te7c4.o" "87li/yqc170h5s20j.o" "87li/yvkj6018hkr2.o" "87li/z96fh9flmvb1.o" "87li/ze1k4o1daxao.o" "87li/zjq5sf0jxwvj.o" "87li/zxkuyiy6p7xl.o" "87li/zzqwu5lthkc4.o" "dqdh/31mb4eijn0rc.o" "dqdh/41ki1812f4ak.o" "zz99/2x31ycfew74i.o" "zz99/3duw0f1mq17l.o" "zz99/50auwti6eb52.o" "zz99/5ygv0jltyau5.o" "zz99/8q1k1ot9r7wg.o" "zz99/af8mibrlgk08.o" "zz99/c3qjycqghyjx.o" "zz99/js7sk1zknd9m.o" "zz99/nv7lyet7ipb0.o" "zz99/p730vz8clvm1.o" "zz99/sds4qz2mpzk9.o" "zz99/tnzifh17zrty.o" "zz99/uzcny9iwvomn.o" "zz99/zk3v4t7u36is.o" -Wl,--wrap,sigaction -fuse-ld=lld.exe -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,-soname=libil2cpp.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -static-libstdc++  -Wl,--icf=safe "D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/src/main/jniStaticLibs/arm64-v8a/baselib.a" -l"log"
Stdout: 
clang++: error: no such file or directory: 'D:/Unity/project/Builds/PlayStore/unityLibrary/src/main/jniStaticLibs/arm64-v8a/baselib.a'

   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(TinyProfiler2 tinyProfiler, String[] args, RuntimePlatform platform, Il2CppCommandLineArguments il2CppCommandLineArguments, BuildingOptions buildingOptions, Boolean throwExceptions)

I tried to re export the project and tried to build it multiple times, and opened it with two different android studio versions and the error persisted.
Would like to know any way to solve this.

The more details don't contain any useful information, search for "what went wrong".

@shingo updated and added full log. Nothing with that search phrase I found.

baselib.a should be found in your Unity installation folder, make sure it wasn't deleted by your antivirus software. If it's missing, try to reinstall Unity.

I have multiple versions of Unity installed and none of the installation folders has the baselib.a. Also the editor can build apk. So reinstalling maybe redundant. I think there is some bug somewhere else.
